# How to see the answers one has given earlier?

Tags: support, android-app, search

How do I see the answers that I gave earlier. This is because I gave an answer to a question long ago but I need to revisit that concept.

*Note:* user:me technique doesn't work for answers one has given, it only works for questions.

Comment: Were they deleted?

Comment: @MonicaCellio no

Comment: @rene doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @rene i m using mobile app

Comment: I can tell you that rene's suggestion works, and I also use the mobile app. You can also go to your profile and use the tools there. Your post may have been deleted; there's no way for you to know without knowing exactly what Q it was posted under.

Comment: @rene android app of Stack Exchange on play store

Comment: @DanBron you can post this as an answer which u'd select.